# Spring Boot with PostgreSQL field to start

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

It is a simple Spring boot CURD application. It failed to start.

In the pom.xml I have as:-

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

There are more decency as well in the pom.

application.properties:-

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=myuser
spring.datasource.password=mypass
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

When try to launch the app, I get the following error:-

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-07-12 15:29:40 [main] ERROR o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

 ***************************
 APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under '' to com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource:

Property: driverclassname
Value: org.postgresql.Driver
Origin: "driverClassName" from property source "source"
Reason: Failed to load driver class org.postgresql.Driver in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader

 Action:

 Update your application's configuration
```

I am confused what did I miss? Please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: which version of postgesql driver you are using ?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. For the version when I expend the external dependency tree, I didn't find any jar for postgressql. After reimport maven dependency, it is added correctly and problem is gone. It is fine now.

Comment: Okey, good luck !